# Angular calling api/account/register

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to register a user via the web api using Angular 2. My call is as follows:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/Authenticated/api/account/register', JSON.stringify(this.cred)).subscribe(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

My form is defined:

```
<form id="userData" (submit)="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="cred.userName" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="cred.password"/>
    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="cred.confirmPassword"/>
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" />
</form>
```

When I make a post I am getting an HTTP415 error:

> HTTP415: UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE - The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your web API mostly for login/register we post form data with this Content-Type `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, otherwise you can use `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: This is on the right track but the Content-Type should be 'application/json'

Comment: I solved it by adding `'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`